# How do I configure arquillian suite extension

Tags: java, testng, jboss-arquillian

How do I configure Arquillian Suite extesion?

https://github.com/it-crowd/arquillian-suite-extension

I would like to use it for single deployment tests, in order not to have to deploy for every single class that have @Test methods in my project.

By the way, I'm using TESTNG with arquillian..

Comment: "not to have to deploy for every single @Test method in my project." - this is wrong statement. Deployment happens for every test class, not method.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. Anyway, I still need it :D

Comment: The fact that there's no readme and tests make me think this may only kind of work thus far.  I believe the guys who wrote it wanted to focus on JUnit.

Comment: With TestNG, you should be able to construct the deployment in the BeforeTest or BeforeSuite and everything in that test or suite should happen in that deployment. This is based on several blogs I've read about Arquillian usage, so YMMV.

Answer (score 5):

I pushed extension bit further, it can be found on maven central and there is part of help written + tests to look how it should be done.

I also created "generic" deployer builder that should work with javaee6.

https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension